Why does the liquid used in Millikan's oil drop experiment need to have zero viscosity?
My teacher said that the viscosity of the liquid used in Millikan's oil drop experiment is ideally zero. But why is that? What advantage does having zero viscosity have in the experiment?

Small or large viscosity makes the bubbles (or drops) to go slower or faster. But, the essence of the experiment is that the bubbles are roughly same size, and they are enough small that even a single electron can make them stop in a field. If the fluid has a low viscosity, I think it makes the measurement easier.

@MattHanson I think we can try to make the question better. I think viscosity might play an important role in the practical reproduction of that experiment, and that would make this question a good one after a fixup. But I am not sure, how to do that.

@peterh Perhaps you could now make your comment an answer.
